# User Identity in ASP.Net modelling

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, asp.net-web-api, user-identification

I have a table with Listings and I want users to be able to mark their favourite listings. To do that I would have a new table with User ID and Listing Id data. Users should be only able to see their favourite listings.

I am using ASP.NET default authentication. The way to get the User Id would be

```
User.Identity.Name;
```

??

Is that the userId I should store? Is that the common approach?

Comment: with the help of `User.Identity.GetUserId()`

Comment: thanks, I had to add "using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;"

Answer (score 0):

The `User.Identity.Name` will have the value of whatever you sign in the user with. For example with forms authentication:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(thisWillBeTheUserIdentityNameValue, false);
```

With claims authentication it will be the value you set for the claim type `ClaimTypes.Name`:

```
var claim = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, thisWillBeTheUserIdentityNameValue)
});
```

If you sign in the user with their user id you could use `User.Identity.Name`.